# How to make image and text closer together in a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button, android-tablelayout

In my project, I have a 3x3 ***TableLayout*** consisting of nine different ***Buttons***. Each ***Button*** has an image drawable above it and a small string of text below it. To be clear, the drawable and text are the ***Buttons*** using the "***drawableTop***" and "***android:text***" variables defined in XML.

I'd like to know that if it would be possible to move the drawable and the text closer together because the UI looks a bit off on big screened phones.

[App on Nexus 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY0L3.png)

[App on Nexus 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61QGf.png)

I realize that I will have to make different XML layout files for small phones, phones, small tablets and big tablets. But Nexus 6 is, as I classify it, a phone so I will probably not be making a separate layout file for it.

Any feedback helps unless you tell me that I need to use a ***LinearLayout*** with an ***ImageButton*** and ***TextView*** in it because I've already tried that and it didn't turn out that well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to this, I usually use two views, one for the text and one for the image and put them into a ViewGroup, which then gets assigned onClickListener. This gives me more freedom and customization with the downside of lowering performance a bit.

But to answer your question, you can use `android:drawablePadding`in conjunction with `android:paddingTop` to control the space between the image and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple answer is probably mess around worth the text view's top padding. If that's not working for you the other solution is using the relative layout which is intended for such cases. That way you can keep the visual effect you're looking for while keeping the layout structure flat which is good for performance.